# First steps to connect to URL: I can not connect and check why on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, httpurlconnection

Im reading this [chapter](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#download), so I'm just trying to connect to a website, but I'm getting an exception after calling `connect()`. The problem is that I don't know how to see what is the problem, since I want to solve it by myself debugging. Here below are pictures. Where can I find the error message to know why it can not connect?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the given snapshots you have opened the debugging tab. Select the `Android Monitor` tab from the bottom which shows all logs. Upon opening the android tab you will see a dropdown with options `verbose, error, info` etc. Select info to see the error logs. Also in the debugging mode, once you reach the `e.printStackTrace()` line, the debugger will show you the value of e which will contain the error information.

Comment: thanks, but I can not see the reason yet.. I have added a pair of images more to my question.

Comment: In debugging mode step over to the stacktrace print line and then you would see the value of exception e.

Comment: @varankr sorry, now I have added the two pictures I mentioned before. Please look at the third one, where can I find the error info?

Comment: e clearly shows a network on main thread exception. That means your network calls are running on main thread. You should run them on a seperate thread.